# TextBox TextChanged Error

Tags: vb.net, winforms, textbox, label

My code needs a little work

```
Public Class Form1
Dim Bread, TotalPrice As Double
Private Sub txtBread_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtBread.TextChanged

    If txtBread.Text = "" Then
        TotalPrice = TotalPrice - Bread
        lblBread.Text = Bread.ToString
        lblPrice.Text = TotalPrice.ToString
    Else
        Bread = Val(txtBread.Text) * 3.25
        lblBread.Text = Bread.ToString
        TotalPrice = TotalPrice + Bread
        lblPrice.Text = TotalPrice.ToString
    End If


End Sub
End Class
```

My textbox is good for a one-digit number only.
So my error here is when i input two-digit numbers on my text box, it actually updates my labels, but when i press backspace it does not update anymore.

Comment: since your txtBread.Text was changed .. your lblPrice.Text should be changed ..

Answer (score 1):

The value of the variable `TotalPrice` grows with each new input (no matter if it is bigger or smaller than the previous one) and thus the value of `lblPrice.Text`. For example:

```
txtBread.Text    TotalPrice     
   1                  1
   15                 16
   1                  17
```

If you explain what you want to accomplish exactly, I can update your code.

```
Dim Bread As Double
Dim TotalPrice as Double = 5 'Any constant value you want
Private Sub txtBread_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtBread.TextChanged

    If txtBread.Text = "" Then
        lblBread.Text = Bread.ToString
        lblPrice.Text = Convert.ToString(TotalPrice - Bread)
    Else
        Bread = Val(txtBread.Text) * 3.25
        lblBread.Text = Bread.ToString
        lblPrice.Text = Convert.ToString(TotalPrice + Bread)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hmmmm. Sorry for my bad english but i hope you can understand.

Comment: When i input "1" on my textbox, my label updates to 3.25
but when i input for example "11" , then i remove one. The price was now wrong due to the fact that my code only works when my textbox is empty(on the if condition)

Comment: For better explanation 
input : 1
output : 3.25

input : 11
when i pressed backspace and deleted "1" on 11
output is now wrong, it does not subtract .

Comment: But my question is: what is TotalPrice for? What do you want to calculate there? The reason why it does not updates back from 11 to 1 is because it is not meant to do so; it is meant to add all the inputted values and this is what it is doing. Please, explain me the exact value you want to display in lblPrice.Text.

Comment: Note that the TextChanged part is behaving perfectly; the problem is the calculations you are doing with this information (TotalPrice).

Comment: Example, I have a fix value for total price for example "5" then i wanted to add the Bread so i added 1 on the textbox, now the total price updates to 5+3.25= 8.25.

Comment: There's something wrong with my condition, when i press backspace once(when i input 2 digit number) it does not subtract, because the condition will only subtract when the textbox has no characters in it. How do i do this?

Comment: You should add an additional object telling when to add/substract. Lots of options: two textboxes (one for values to add and another one for values to substract), a checkbox (when checked the values would be substracted, otherwise added), an indication in the textbox (for example, if you input "a" after the given number would mean to be added, otherwise substracted), etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try with my sample ..

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim Bread As Double
    Dim TotalPrice As Double = 100 '---> maybe this is a result from a function

    Private Sub txtBread_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtBread.TextChanged

        If txtBread.Text = "" Then
            Bread = 0
        Else
            Bread = Val(txtBread.Text) * 3.25
        End If
        lblBread.Text = Bread.ToString
        lblPrice.Text = (TotalPrice + Bread).ToString
    End Sub
End Class
```